# "The result set is closed." error after executing

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdbc

I am trying to perform 3 operations on Database.

1. Count the number of rows (with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestCaseTable`)
2. Insert a row
3. Again count the number of rows

This is to assert that the row has be successfully inserted in Database.

Here is the stub which is performing these operations:

```
try {
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
    Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    statement = connection.createStatement();

    System.out.println("Checking before Insertion");
    ResultSet beforeinsertResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestCaseTable");
    beforeinsertResultSet.next();
    int beforeInsertRowCount = beforeinsertResultSet.getInt(1);
    System.out.println("Before Insert "+beforeInsertRowCount);

    String insertTCQuery = "Insert into TestCaseTable ([Test Case Id], [Test Module Name], [Test Priority], [Test Designed By], "
            + "[Test Designed Date], [Test Executed By], [Test Execution Date], [Test Title], [Test Summary], [Pre-Condition],"
            + " [Dependencies], [Test Steps], [Test Data], [Expected result], [Post-Condition], [Actual Result], "
            + "[Test Status], [Notes]) "
            + "Values ('"+ testCaseIdIs +"', '"+ moduleNameIs +"', '"+ priorityIs +"', '"+ testDesignerIs +"', '"+ testDesignDateIs +"', "
                    + "'"+ testExecutedByIs +"', '"+ testExecutionDateIs +"', '"+ titleNameIs +"', '"+ descriptionIs +"', "
                            + "'"+ preConditionIs +"', '"+ dependenciesIs +"', '"+ testStepsIs +"', '"+ testDataIs +"',"
                                    + "'"+ expectedResultsIs +"', '"+ postConditionIs +"', '"+ actualResultIs +"', '"+ testStstusIs +"', "
                                            + "'"+ notesIs +"')";


    statement.executeUpdate(insertTCQuery);

    System.out.println("Checking after Insertion");
    ResultSet afterinsertResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestCaseTable");
    afterinsertResultSet.next();
    int afterInsertRowCount = beforeinsertResultSet.getInt(1);
    System.out.println("Before Insert "+afterInsertRowCount);

    if(afterInsertRowCount == beforeInsertRowCount+1) {
        statusLabel.setText("Inserted Successfully!");
        statusLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        statusLabel.setText("Error Inserting Test Case.");
    }

    beforeinsertResultSet.close();
    afterinsertResultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();

} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Checking before Insertion Before Insert 11 Checking after Insertion
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is
>   closed.   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.checkClosed(SQLServerResultSet.java:372)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2309)
>     at
>   com.gs.SaveTestCases.SaveTestCase$ButtonClickListener.actionPerformed(SaveTestCase.java:321)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

As you can see that, First row count and insertion gets executed successfully but the third operation(count DB row again) gives error that "`The result set is closed`".

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
What all I have tried which did not worked in my case:

1. I created new Connection (`connection1`), statement (`statement1`) and used these for second time row count.
2. I have closed `beforeinsertResultSet` after insertion

Comment: try with closing your previous result set before opening a new one

Comment: The [documentation of `java.sql.Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says clearly: _By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time._

Comment: Also, to assert row is successfully inserted or not, use the variable returned by 'statement.executeUpdate(insertTCQuery);'.
Example:
'int count = statement.executeUpdate(insertTCQuery);
if(count>0){//inserted successfully}

Comment: @XtremeBaumer & @ RealSkeptic 
I tried both the logics, but didn`t worked

Comment: @Amit1011 On using count for the insertion statement, it will give me `1` as output. But if the insertion fails, this will not be applicable

Comment: add else block to this if(count>0) block; so that you can do whatever you are doing here:
if(afterInsertRowCount == beforeInsertRowCount+1) {
        statusLabel.setText("Inserted Successfully!");
        statusLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        statusLabel.setText("Error Inserting Test Case.");
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this fails your code:

```
 int afterInsertRowCount = beforeinsertResultSet.getInt(1);
```

replace it with

```
int afterInsertRowCount = afterinsertResultSet.getInt(1);
```

this `beforeinsertResultSet` is closed after you execute the update statement

where to find the code:

```
ResultSet afterinsertResultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestCaseTable");
afterinsertResultSet.next();
int afterInsertRowCount = beforeinsertResultSet.getInt(1);
System.out.println("Before Insert "+afterInsertRowCount);
```

Comment: Nice catch sir,
Sorry, it was my bad.